# How can I fix: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Map<any, any>' ts(2339)

Tags: typescript

Very new to typescript but I need to move my javascript over to a ts file.

Had a bunch of errors but most could be fixed by adding ":any" after the variable

However, I'm getting a Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Map<any, any>'.ts(2339) error

The error is happening on the 2 .map keyword occurrences below

```
function process(raw)  {
    const sortCompare = (a:any, b:any) => a.order - b.order;
    const data = d3
      .rollup(
        raw,
        (v:any) => {
          const agg = d3
            .rollup(
              v,
              (vv:any) => vv,
              (d:any) => d.Attribute + d.ChildOrder
            )
            .map((d:any) => ({
              name: d[1][0].Attribute,
              type: d[1][0].Type,
              parentOrder: d[1][0].ParentOrder,
              order: d[1][0].ChildOrder,
              value: d[1][0].Value,
              adjustment: d[1][0].Adjustment,
              children: d[1],
            }));

          agg.sort(sortCompare);

          const parent = agg.filter((d) => d.type == "Parent")[0];
          const children = agg.filter((d) => d.type == "Child");

          children.parent = parent;
          return children;
        },
        (d:any) => d.Group
      ) 
      .map((d:any) => ({
        name: d[0],
        type: "Group",
        order: d[1].parent.parentOrder,
        value: d[1].parent.value,
        adjustment: d[1].parent.adjustment,
        children: d[1],
      }));
```

How can I fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't know how the code worked in js - `rollup` returns a `Map`, (actually a `d3.internMap`), that doesn't have the function `.map` (neither in js, nor in ts). Try using [rollups](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#rollups) that returns an array. Also, you know your own business better, but I have to say that you most likely can define more specific types than `any` to make typescript useful.

Comment: My bad,  I changed rollups to rollup after it was suggested in vs code:  "  Property 'rollups' does not exist on type 'typeof import("c***")'. Did you mean 'rollup'?ts(2551) "

Any idea?  When I revert to rollups I get this error?

Comment: `rollups` is defined [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/d3-array/index.d.ts)